# Changing WinRM settings from Script

Tags: group-policy, scripting, winrm

I am trying to change winrm's allow basic authentication property from command line.

Following is my command

```
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="false"}
```

I get a message that this is controlled by GPO

```
WSManFault
Message
    ProviderFault
        WSManFault
            Message = The config setting Basic cannot be changed because is
                      controlled by policies. 
                      The policy would need to be set to "Not Configured" in 
                      order to change the config setting.

Error number:  -2144108406 0x8033808A
Cannot change GPO controlled setting.
```

My command prompt is running in administrative mode.

I can go to gpedit.msc and change theses properties manually but I would like override GPO settings from command prompt. IS there a way this can be done?

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: You can delete the policy's reg key(s) but that's not really nice is it?

Comment: @jscott well if that's the last resort then I can try. Do you know where are they located?

Comment: The `AllowBasic` key is under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client`. Even if you delete it, upon Group Policy refresh, it will come back.

Comment: jscott, can you post that as an answer? Setting the various settings to allowed helped get me working. Changing directly in Group Policy editor didn't work on its own due to restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

- Edit Group Policy.
- Administrative Templates -> Windows Component -> Winodws Remote Management(WinRM) -> WinRM Client -> make all as not configured
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSCol.png)
- Administrative Templates -> Windows Component -> Winodws Remote Management(WinRM) -> WinRM Service-> make Allow Basic authentication as not configured
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgdFa.png)

-Open powershell and run # `gpupdate /force`

now it will work for you